# SQL Inner join show numeric value once

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, unique

I know my question is not very logical but I have the folowing chalenge:

```
HeadTab (Uniq_Id  N(10)
         Name   C(30)
         Tax N(18,2))

TrsTab (Uniq_Id N(10) 
        MonthlyDesc C(20)
        Amount N(18,2))
```

What I want is the following `select * from headtab inner join Trstab on uniq_id = Uniq_id`

the issue is that I want to see the tax field only once per name other related should be 0...(Eventhough I have many lines in the details tab).

Thank you for any help

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this. Top, Distinct, Max/Min/Other Aggregate. From what you posted it is not really possible to help much more than that.

Comment: why would you not want to see the Tax value on every row?  and what are you ordering by to know which row is the first row per Name?

Comment: One way to see the same tax field based on name is to use a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the query a row number to determine the first row for each Name you can use a case statement to select which value you want for Tax.

```
SELECT
    ht.Uniq_ID,
    ht.NAME,
    (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ht.NAME ORDER BY ht.Uniq_ID) = 1 THEN ht.Tax ELSE 0 END)  Tax,
    tt.*
FROM
    headtab ht
    INNER JOIN Trstab tt ON ht.uniq_id = tt.Uniq_id
```